# Artillery Sidewinder X1 3DTouch not working

Tags: marlin, firmware, bed-leveling, 3dtouch, artillery-sidewinder-x1

The printer I am working on is an Artillery Sidewinder X1.

I have fitted it with a 3DTouch (BLTouch clone) bed leveling probe purchased from Bangood.

I have printed a mount for it and plugged it into the main board. Once that was done, I edited the firmware and enabled all settings for the 3DTouch roughly following the directions from Teaching Tech's video [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUlqrSq6LeY)
After flashing the firmware, an error message appears on every boot saying:

```
Failed to enable Bed Leveling
echo: Bed Leveling off echo:
Fade Height Off ok
```

After pressing confirm, ABL routine does not work. It homes the X-axis, then the Y-axis, deploys and stows the 3DTouch probe once. It also will show an error message for a split second (so I am unable to know what it says) the comes up with an EEPROM message.

Auto homing does the same thing as ABL routine but with a different error:

```
STOP called because of BLTouch
error - restart with M999
Error:Printer stopped due to errors.
Fix the error and use
M999 to restart. (Temperature
is reset. Set it after res[e]t
```

I have also zipped up my Marlin firmware configuration I am currently using. They can be found here: [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yyqZGCIfUeY0QV9oFfd2kbMpiZjwPLaY/view?usp=sharing)

My servo pin is connected to D11 and my two wire pin is connected to the ZMAX endstop. Here is a diagram:

[image: 3DTouch Wiring]

Comment: My personal experiences with 3DTouch is that they are of inferior quality opposed to the original, at first they work (most of the times), but they will break fast (from experience, I've had about 4 of them on different printers, all died eventually).

Comment: @0scar I made this post almost half a year ago now when I first bought the sensor. It has been working fine ever since and I have never had a problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I did a bit of testing with the wiring and it turns out I just had the 3DTouch in the Z- socket instead of Z+ :-) .
Another idiot mistake from me!